# i changed my wordpress address url in SETTINGS - GENRERAL - wordpress address site url. cannot login anymore

Tags: options

i changed my wordpress address url in SETTINGS - GENRERAL - wordpress address site url. cannot login anymore.
I have tried all sorts of tutorials to get to login to my admin page with no success.
Things i gave tried : 1.editing wp-config.php define('WP_HOME',http:/example.com);
define('WP_SITEURL','http:/example.com');
2. Gone into my php admin and changed wp-options site url and home.
3. added the define('RELOCATE',true); into wp-config.php.

What next? I would appreciate it a lot if someone is willing to go into my site via cpanel and see what is going on. I am really stuck now and need urgent help Please.
I cannot remember what the origanal wrodpress address site url was.Is there a place where you can look it up.
my site
Path : /home/africaphoto/public_html/wp
URL : http://africaphotogalleries.co.za/wp
Admin URL : http://africaphotogalleries.co.za/wp/wp-admin/
Admin Username : admin
Admin Password : ********
Admin Email: [email redacted] MySQL Database : africaphoto_wp735 MySQL DB User : africaphoto_wp735 MySQL DB Host : localhost MySQL DB Password : ******** Update Notification : Enabled Auto Upgrade : Disabled Automated Backups : Disabled Time of Installation : March 27, 2017, 5:48 pm

This info above is straight from the softaculous installation email.  I cannot remember what the origanal wrodpress address site url was.

Comment: have you fully flushed your browsers cache?

Comment: Try: `define('WP_HOME', 'http://africaphotogalleries.co.za/wp/');` and `define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://africaphotogalleries.co.za/wp/');`

Note the ending `/wp/`

Besides, seem that you have duplicated WordPress source code at `root` and `root/wp`, usually you need one of them only

Comment: Have access to phpmyadmin? Then simply go to your wp_options table and the first 2 entries are the ones you can change back to whatever url you want